# Finding the length of a linked list in python

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

```
def len_link(lst):

"""Returns the length of the link.

    >>> lst = link(1, link(2, link(3, link(4))))
    >>> len_link(lst)
    4
    >>> len_link(empty)
    0
    """
```

Hi I'm having a hard time understanding how to find the length of a linked list if someone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This kind of begs the question *why* you'd want to create linked lists in a language that already natively *has* lists and the means to iterate over them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in ["Functional linked lists in Python"](https://dbader.org/blog/functional-linked-lists-in-python):

> The length operation returns the number of elements in a given list.
>   To find the length of a list we need to scan all of its n elements.
>   Therefore this operation has a time complexity of O(n).
>
> ```
> def length(xs):
>     if is_empty(xs):
>         return 0
>     else:
>         return 1 + length(tail(xs))
>
> assert length(lst(1, 2, 3, 4)) == 4
> assert length(Nil) == 0
> ```
>
> head and tail are respectively:
>
> ```
> def head(xs):
>     return xs[0]
>
> assert head(lst(1, 2, 3)) == 1
> def tail(xs):
>     return xs[1]
>
> assert tail(lst(1, 2, 3, 4)) == lst(2, 3, 4)
> ```

Comment: So you're adding 1 to length(tail(xs)) to do it recursively in order to find how iterations you go through right?

Comment: Exactly so. Its like a counter.

Comment: When you copy the words of another, you must place the copied text inside a blockquote to indicate these are not your words. The reference link must come before the quoted text. I've corrected the above, but please make sure you provide proper attribution in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this:

```
def len_link(list):
    temp=list.head
    count=0
    while(temp):
        count+=1
        temp=temp.next
    return count
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
def lengthRecursive(head):
    if head is None:
        return 0
    else:
       return 1 + lengthRecursive(head.next)
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI: 2-line Python snippets to count the length of a singly linked-list

```py
# iterative
n, curr = 0, head
while curr: n, curr = n + 1, curr.next

# recursive
def length(head: ListNode):
    return 0 if not head else 1 + length(head.next)
```