# Python Linked List length

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in python and a function that computes the length of a linked list. Here is the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, nxt=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nxt = nxt
```

```
def length(node):
    if not node:
        return 0
    return 1 + length(node.nxt)
```

But my jupyter notebook raises an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'nxt'`.

Do you have any idea where it comes from / how I can prevent it to make the code work?

I found a very similar question ([Finding the length of a linked list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333462/finding-the-length-of-a-linked-list-in-python)), but the implementation I used was only in the answers so I couldn't directly reply to that answer (I could only comment with 15 characters).

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

Sorry I didn't read the comments during the week-end, but here is the code in which I use the snippets above. As @juanpa.arrivillaga guessed it is for an exercise indeed. And @D4NieLDev I guess you're right that I pass an int instead of a `Node` object but I am not sure how to do it right.

```
def intersection(a, b):
    m, n = length(a), length(b)
    cur_a, cur_b = a, b
    
    if m > n:
        for _ in range(m - n):
            cur_a = cur_a.nxt
        
    else:
        for _ in range(n - m):
            cur_b = cur_b.nxt
    
    while cur_a != cur_b:
        cur_a = cur_a.nxt
        cur_b = cur_b.nxt
        
    return cur_a
```

This is a function that should find the intersecting node of two linked lists, and here are the lists:

```
a3 = Node(10, nxt=None)
a2 = Node(8, nxt=a3)
a1 = Node(7, nxt=a2)
a0 = Node(3, nxt=a1)

b3 = Node(10, nxt=None)
b2 = Node(8, nxt=b3)
b1 = Node(1, nxt=b2)
b0 = Node(99, nxt=b1)
```

And I call the function so:

```
intersection(a0, b0)
```

**Edit no. 2**:
The code above now works properly as regards the `length()` function, but not as regards the `intersection()` function, which just yields nothing. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Could you show the code, where you are creating the nodes and calling the `length` method?

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]. Note, in general you should avoid recursion in python, due to the recursion limit being rather restrictive (around 1000)

Comment: It seems like you are passing an integer instead of a `Node` object.

Comment: Instead of creating a new function for finding length, better to use a length variable in linked list class that gets incremented at every insertion and decremented at every deletion. This function will only add extra cost to your program.

Comment: @DashrathChauhan yes, I suppose this is all for an academic exercise though. You would rarely ever need to implement a linked list in Python. But yeah, just keeping track of the length internally would be the most time efficient way to do this.

Comment: It would be good if you would show some interest in the comments that are placed here. So far we only see silence from your part... Please add the code that illustrates the problem, so we can run it and see the same happening.

Comment: thanks for your answers! I'll do some research on this recursion limit that I didn't know of and try to implement a length variable. Apart from these, how could I pass a ``Node`` object instead of an integer as D4NieLDev recommends?

Comment: "here are the lists" Those aren't lists. Those are individual Nodes. Neither Python nor your class knows that ``nxt=8`` refers to ``b2`` just because its ``data`` happens to be 8. Use something like ``b1 = Node(1, nxt=b1)`` instead.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, my internet connexion didn't update quickly enough for me to see your comment before I wrote mine below, but I also tried that without any change in the result and any error from Python. Another question I have is since we are now talking about real lists because ``nxt=a1`` and others are now better defined, should I not get rid of the ``Node()`` in ``self.nxt = Node(nxt) if nxt else None``? I just tried that and the ``length()`` function now works well, but the ``intersection()`` function still yields no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer was so obvious I didn't see it. The problem was in the `intersection()` function as I was directly comparing `Node` object between themselves instead of comparing their values, and when running the `length()` function there was no other problem. Thanks to everybody who answered, it made me understand what I did much better!